# dynamic display of checkbox - vs2008,c#

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want to display check boxes, whose count is dynamic. The display should be similar to google 'create your home page' section, see attached.

[Sample page display](http://i54.tinypic.com/2nvfqty.jpg)

bump

Answer (score 0):

Create a checkbox using the Designer in Visual Studio, then open up your main form's Form.Designer.cs file and look at the code it created.  You can replicate that in a loop.

Comment: I can use repeater, but unsure how i can control them column wise..if i have to expand it to allow paging then i have to be at drawing board. wonder if there is a mix of gridview and repeater as grid view can get me paging if needed..

Comment: Are you asking how to dynamically reposition them based on changes in windows size?

Comment: Say my window size is fixed. I want to display 5 items per row. and if i want to display 4 rows per page, i would need paging to display row 5...onward. if you look at the pic i have with this post, row 1 and 2 contain 4 items. row 3 has only 3 items. i assume that is done dynamically....

Comment: @qazwsx: A repeater is probably the way to go here. You can mimic a tabular layout with CSS styles, particularly `float`. In fact, many HTML/CSS designers prefer to do it this way, avoiding `table` tags (which a GridView turns into) for accessibility reasons. Besides, repeaters are just more flexible versions of GridViews; you can easily construct an HTML `table` with one if you like, using any layout you choose.

Comment: @Justin Morgan: BTW, I did a double-take when I saw your name.

Comment: @E There is at least one more on SO as well.